# Catching Numpy All-Nan Slice

Tags: python, numpy, nan

I have an issue trying to catch a Python exception:

> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/nanfunctions.py",
>   line 427, in nanargmax
>       raise ValueError("All-NaN slice encountered") ValueError: All-NaN slice encountered

The error appears with this code when effectively the slice contains All-NaN. However, I want to catch that situation and handle it.

```
with warnings.catch_warnings():
   warnings.filterwarnings('error')
try:
    action = np.nanargmax(self.Q[state])
except Warning as e:
    print "error"
    sys.exit(0)
```

I expect to print the word error, however, the try-except statement is ignored. Any help, please?

Comment: Why are you trying to go through the warning system for a `ValueError`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should change `except Warning as e` to `except ValueError as e`.

This is because the `ValueError` class is not a subclass of the `Warning` class. Alternatively, you could catch any `Exception` with `except Exception as e` since all exceptions are a subclass of the `Exception` class, but best practice is to be as precise as possible with the exceptions that you catch.

Comment: Precisely, the final working code was this one:                try:
                action = np.nanargmax(self.Q[state])
            except ValueError:
                action = random.randint(0, num_states - 1)